# How to control the owner of the merge commit in Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket

Bitbucket seems to want to make the person performing the merge of a PR the owner of the merge. I would like it to be the author of changes included in the merge, and not the person performing the merge, as these will usually not be the same, and just because someone else approves a PR doesn't mean that the merger necessarily deserves to be the owner of all the changes.

The current setting renders "git blame" useless.

I can't find any obvious way of controlling this, is there a plugin or some other technique to select the owner of the merge commit when accepting a pull request?

Comment: Bitbucket Cloud or Bitbucket Server?

Comment: Bitbucket Server... our merge strategy is squash and merge.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option for doing what you want in Bitbucket Cloud (the bitbucket.org version) from the interface. The reason why is that they take the premise that to keep the whole history you need a merge-commit, and that in fact the merge commit has a responsible author. Despite that philosophy on their cloud version, they do have multiple additional merge strategies in the enterprise version of Bitbucket Server that achieve your end result (there have to be reasons to buy that product, after all, and many companies have a 'clean repo history' policy that requires them to avoid merge-commits).

However, you can still achieve what you want (and avoid the merge-commit) if you manually rebase in your branch, do the merge and then push it to the remote. See the following example (assuming that you want to merge into master, and that your default remote is your bitbucket repo):

```
# From master get the latest commits
git pull
# Switch to your branch
git checkout my-branch
# Rebase into master
git rebase master
# go back to master
git checkout master
# merge your branch without creating a merge commit
git merge my-branch
# push to Bitbucket (which effectively closes the pull request if there was one)
git push
```

Comment: So we do have the enterprise version, and the merge strategy we chose was squash and merge. On a purely mechanical level, it makes sense that this commit would belong to the merger, but from a process perspective, it's nonsense.

Comment: It really depends on what you want. If the merger is squashing the commits into the target branch, like you're doing, then the new commit will belong to the "merger" because he/she is taking the additional action of squashing. If you really need the squash, you might have to tell your developers to squash themselves their pull request and push force it to the branch, before you merge, and then you'll be able to use the `Rebase, fast-forward` merge strategy to preserve the autorship of the merged commits.

Comment: Tools exist to implement process and simplify things. One shouldn't have to work around limitations like these. Fast forward makes no sense when you have hundreds of committers, all racing to be at HEAD....

Comment: I guess the simple answer is "you can't", and probably the right answer is "use gerrit" :)